# Is my PCI-e setup proposal technically possible?

Tags: graphics-cards, pcie, adapter

I have a question for the connoisseurs of PCI-e technology and graphics cards. I have an [old NUC](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/81164/intel-nuc-kit-d54250wykh.html) lying around in a closet. It has a specific case where there is more space than the Intel one.
Also, it has a mini PCI-e (x1) Gen2 slot.

I want to recycle it into a retro console and old PC games. To upgrade it a little bit, I found on the internet :

- [mini PCI-e (x1) to PCI-e (x1) adapters](https://www.amazon.fr/ADT-Link-Riser-Demi-mPCIe-Gen3-0-PCI-Express/dp/B084HDF68L)
- [adapters for MXM graphics card to PCI-e(x1)](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32952012735.html)
- [MXM GPUs](https://www.ebay.com/itm/184685889610)

I intend to make the following assembly:

`MXM GPU > MXM to PCI-e (x1) adapter > PCI-e (x1) to mini PCI-e (x1) adapter > NUC`
[image: Setup]

I understand it is uncommon, but beyond the financial or performance aspect, do you think that this assembly could be **technically** feasible?

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: I have no idea, but I just wanna say I love this post.  Improvise adapt adapt adapt adapt overcome :).

Comment: How about use a regular GPU, and adapt its output?  The external GPU will have a standard 6 or 8 pin plug.  Then use a PC power supply to power the whole thing, and it will automatically have the necessary plugs and volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not going to work.
The mini pcie card can supply a peak power of 3.3V at 1A.
From what I can find an mxm gpu always needs more power than this and unlike a normal gpu it has no external connections.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. Other people in another forum told me also that it should not work due the fact that the motherboard has to skip Intel integrated graphics which is not feasible in my BIOS.